# Identification of Jumping Spider Species

Tags: species-identification, entomology, taxonomy, arachnology

I found this jumping spider (Salticidae family) in **Pune/India**. Most common species of jumpers in my region is heavy-bodied jumper (Hyllus semicupreus), but this is different species by observing body size and blue colored patch under eyes. Its size was about 7mm-8mm. 
[image] 
[image]